# Notepad++ | Regex Find/replace values

Tags: notepad++, regexp-replace

I have data in the below format

```
(‘A’,’ b’,*null*,’c’)
(‘D’,null,’*e,f*’,’g’)
(‘1’,’2’,’*4,5,6*’,null)
```

I have around 300 rows of similar data..
required to change all the data in *italics* to `‘N’`, which is the third field..
all the remaining data need to be as it is.

I am new to `notepad++`.

Is there a way we can do using regex??

Tried txt to columns in excel, but didn’t work

Comment: To be clear, you want to modify the 3rd value only, don't you? Please show us your expected result. There are apostrophes around values, are they really apostrophs or single quotes?

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\((?:'.+?'|null),(?:'.+?'|null),\K(?:'.+?'|null)`
- Replace with: `'N'`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\(                  # opening parenthesis
(?:'.+?'|null)      # non capture group, 1 or more any character between single quotes OR literally "null"
,                   # a comma
(?:'.+?'|null)      # non capture group, 1 or more any character between single quotes OR literally "null"
,                   # a comma
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
(?:'.+?'|null)      # non capture group, 1 or more any character between single quotes OR literally "null"
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]